# ImportError: No module named 'llvmlite.llvmpy.ee'

Tags: python, python-3.x, llvm, numba, llvmlite

I need to use Numba on a cluster running on Centos 7.

However, the IT team could not install llvm 4.0 (no builder for Centos 7), so they installed llvm 3.9.

After, I successfully installed llvmlite 0.16.0 and Numba 0.17 using pip.

Unfortunately, when I start a simple test program, I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'llvmlite.llvmpy.ee'`

Here is the complete error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "LINCS_Test.py", line 17, in
>
> ```
> import KerasImageDataGenerator as kidg
> ```
>
> File "../KerasImageDataGenerator.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import KerasBatchTransformation2D as bt
> ```
>
> File "../KerasBatchTransformation2D.py", line 1, in
>
> ```
> import numba
> ```
>
> File
>
> "/home/exacloud/lustre1/gray_lab/users/Guillaume/Python/lib/python3.4/site-
>
> packages/numba/**init**.py", line 6, in
>
> ```
> from . import testing, decorators
> ```
>
> File
>
> "/home/exacloud/lustre1/gray_lab/users/Guillaume/Python/lib/python3.4/site-
>
> packages/numba/decorators.py", line 7, in
>
> ```
> from .targets import registry
> ```
>
> File
>
> "/home/exacloud/lustre1/gray_lab/users/Guillaume/Python/lib/python3.4/site-
>
> packages/numba/targets/registry.py", line 3, in
>
> ```
> from . import cpu
> ```
>
> File "/home/exacloud/lustre1/gray_lab/users/Guillaume/Python/lib/python3.4/site-
>   packages/numba/targets/cpu.py", line 6, in
>
> ```
> import llvmlite.llvmpy.ee as le
> ```
>
> ImportError: No module named 'llvmlite.llvmpy.ee'

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `llvmlite` repository contains a [table of compatible LLVM versions](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite#compatibility). Currently it reads:

```
llvmlite versions   compatible LLVM versions
0.17.0 - ...        4.0.x
0.16.0 - 0.17.0     3.9.x
0.13.0 - 0.15.0     3.8.x
0.9.0 - 0.12.1      3.7.x
0.6.0 - 0.8.0       3.6.x
0.1.0 - 0.5.1       3.5.x
```

And the numba repository maintains a file listing the requirements for `llvmlite`: [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/requirements.txt). Currently the requirement is:

```
llvmlite>=0.20
```

However it [seems](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/0.33.0/requirements.txt) like Numba 0.33 had a requirement compatible with LLVM 3.9.x:

```
llvmlite>=0.16
```

So you probably need to use Numba 0.33.x if you want to work with LLVM 3.9. Given that numba is/was rapidly changing it seems likely that any version before numba 0.30 (first one to require llvmlite 0.16) or after 0.33 (last one to accepting llvmlite 0.16) won't work because the API changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For unknown weird reason, pip automatically installed numba 0.17. Now that I've upgrade to 0.33, it works. It's not that I want to work with llvm 3.9, it's just that I must because llvm 4.0 could not be installed on the cluster.